# RuntimeException: setParameters failed on some redmi devices

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

```
camera = openCamera();
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, cameraInfo);
mParameters = camera.getParameters();
mParameters.setRotation(90);
mParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
mParameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
mParameters.setJpegQuality(85);
List<Camera.Size> cameraSize = mParameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
mPreviewSize = cameraSize.get(0);// get top size
for (int i = 0; i < cameraSize.size(); i++) {
    if (cameraSize.get(i).width > mPreviewSize.width) {
        mPreviewSize = cameraSize.get(i);
    }
}
//set max Picture Size
mParameters.setPictureSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
camera.setParameters(mParameters); // line 46
```

> **getting below exception** java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3190)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
>                                                                                 at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1964)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.tmw.mobilewallet.corporateportal.utils.Preview.(Preview.java:46)

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are your inputs and expected outputs? We need more context than this.

Comment: i am trying to create custom camera, in some devices it working perfectly.

Comment: most likely, this device does not support FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE, but I won't be shocked if the cause is setRotation(90) or that the aspect ratio of Picture is different from the aspect ratio of the Preview.

Comment: Issue with FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE
Some devices not support this mode. Thanks all of you

Comment: I also have this problem with parameters.setPreviewSize(..). I have read that this is caused because the camera API 2 is disabled and would work after enabling.
Is there some other way (for camera API 1)? Thanks